# Pandas dataframe slicing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    2012   2013   2014   2015  2016   2017   2018                 Kategorie
0   5.31   5.27   5.61   4.34   4.54   5.02   7.07  Gewinn pro Aktie in EUR
1  13.39  14.70  12.45  16.29  15.67  14.17  10.08                      KGV
2 -21.21  -0.75   6.45 -22.63  -7.75   9.76  47.52           Gewinnwachstum
3 -17.78   2.27  -0.55   3.39   1.48   0.34    NaN                      PEG
```

Now, I am selecting only the `KGV` row with:

```
df[df["Kategorie"] == "KGV"]
```

Which outputs:

```
    2012  2013   2014   2015  2016   2017   2018  Kategorie
1  13.39  14.7  12.45  16.29  15.67  14.17  10.08       KGV
```

How do I calculate the `mean()` of the last five years (2016,15,14,13,12 in this example)?
I tried

```
df[df["Kategorie"] == "KGV"]["2016":"2012"].mean()
```

but this throws a `TypeError`. Why can I not slice the columns here?

Comment: Why are the last five years 2012-2016?

Comment: As soon as you start trying to slice with  `__getitem__` (square-bracket indexing), [pandas looks at the rows](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#l2043) not the columns. Also the slice only works forwards. Your indexing in this case can be done using `df.loc[df["Kategorie"] == "KGV", "2012":"2016"]` instead.

Comment: @AmiTavory: *Last* as in *from now on **backwards***. Not last as in the last elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loc` supports that type of slicing (from left to right):

```
df.loc[df["Kategorie"] == "KGV", "2012":"2016"].mean(axis=1)
Out: 
1    14.5
dtype: float64
```

Note that this does not necessarily mean 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016. These are strings so it means all columns between `df['2012']` and `df['2016']`. There could be a column named `foo` in between and it would be selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! There's no `foo` column in between and the columns are sorted per year.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the last five years are 2012-2016 (they seem to be the *first* five years). Notwithstanding, to find the mean for 2012-2016 for `'KGV'`, you can use

```
df[df['Kategorie'] == 'KGV'][[c for c in df.columns if c != 'Kategorie' and 2012 <= int(c) <= 2016]].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: *Last* as in *from now **backwards***. Why should this be used in contrast to @ayhan's approach?

Comment: @Jan No reason in particular - I answered it before his, but I like his more.

Answer (score 2):

I used `filter` and `iloc`

```
row = df[df.Kategorie == 'KGV']

row.filter(regex='\d{4}').sort_index(1).iloc[:, -5:].mean(1)

1    13.732
dtype: float64
```